# ¿Como descargar archivos con VueJS que se envían desde un backend con ExpressJS?

Tags: nodejs, vue.js, express, axios

Tengo una duda, no se cuál es la mejor manera de descargar un archivo `zip` que envío desde el `backend` (ExpressJS) a mi `frontend` (VueJS).

Cuando los archivos no son tan pesados, la tarea es sencilla, en teoría. Pero cuando pesan más de 7GB, comienza el dilema. Tal vez no me expresá bien, pero con el código lo aclararé:

La ruta en la cual envío el archivo al `frontend`:

```
app.get('/muygrande',validaToken, async(req, res) => {
  console.log('descargando');
  await res.download('../repositorio/muygrande.zip');
});
```

Así recibo el archivo en el cliente:

```
<button @click="jsDowloand">descargar</button>
```

Mediante Axios, consumo la ruta del `backend` :

```
 jsDowloand() {
  alert('muygrande');
  this.$axios('/muygrande')
  .then( async resp => {
      this.forceFileDownload(resp);
  })
  .catch( erro => console.log(erro));
},
forceFileDownload(response) {
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
  const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = url;
  link.setAttribute("download", "file.zip"); //or any other extension
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
}
```

Comprendo que mediante esta metodología es complejo hacer una carga de tanta cantidad de datos, pero no conozco otra manera diferente en VueJS.

La vía mas fácil sería  con una etiqueta de hipervínculo, que apunte a la ruta del `backend` y dilema solucionado, pero me tocaría quitar el `token` de autentificación, a no ser que en el hipervínculo se pueda enviar el `token`.

Pero las cosas que van por `GET` no las veo de verdad muy seguras, si alguien tiene alguna idea de otra forma como lo podría realizar, realmente se lo agradecería.

Comment: `res.download()` fuerza la descarga de dicho archivo, solo necesitas agregar un hyperlink `<a href="/muyGrande">Descargar</a>`

Comment: Otra opción es que uses la API de javascript `FileSystem`

Comment: el problema seria, que  tengo un middleware, el cual validara que la petición traiga un token de sesión, si no lo trae dará un 401, mediante el hyperlink, podría enviar un token?, si no la petición sera rechazada

Comment: Tambien podrias crear tokens temporales, guardar ese token creado en una base de datos con un tiempo límite, digamos una hora y después de esa hora el token caduca y generas otro. Y con un cron job eliminar los tokens caducados mediante una sentencia

Comment: Hola @R3d3r82, estoy intentando crear algo asi pero no he logrado generarlo correctamente, crees que podrias hecharme la mano?